# kdm cannot authorize my user?

Tags: vmware, authorization

I've upgraded my virtual machine from Opensuse 12.2 M3 to 12.2 Beta 1 and it hangs at the startup after the mysqld. However I can manually access a terminal and start kdm as root but kdm doesn't recognize my user? I have double checked the password and it's not a typo? I don't have special character like here http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58623-Can-t-login-via-KDM-after-upgrading-to-Precise/page1, too.

Comment: What is '12.2 M3' and '12.2 Beta'?

Comment: opensuse 12.2 M3 ...

Comment: What is in your logs? Check `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/kdm.log`. Are there any informations about failed logins?

Comment: @pbm: It was .xinitrc missing the line exec startkde.

Comment: @David: post it as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my .xinitrc missing the line exec startkde and cannot start a windowmanager.